# Value Converter doesn't work in CustomControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, converters

I tried to use the control from [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/741026/WPF-FlipView) - FlipView Control.
Here is what I have:

```
<flipViewControl:FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" Name="ImagesFlipView"
                                            SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=ProductImagesBullets, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0">
    <flipViewControl:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding FileLocation, Converter={StaticResource ImagePathConverter}}" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </flipViewControl:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</flipViewControl:FlipView>
```

`ImagePathConverter` set ImageSource:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUri"], value);

    var bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand;
    bi.UriSource = new Uri(url);
    bi.EndInit();
    return bi.Clone();
}
```

But in this user control, in Debug, I never get inside this converter (When I tried it on a simple alone image, it works).

What can be the solution for this problem? (Images aren't displayed, because converter doesn't apply correct ImageSource for Image)

---

I have created a test project with this control and converter - it works... Strange, very strange

---

UPD : Now it seems like

```
<flipViewControl:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileLocation}"></TextBlock>
                                                    <!--<Image Source="{Binding FileLocation, Converter={StaticResource ImagePathConverter}}" Stretch="Fill"/>-->
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </flipViewControl:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
```

doesn't work at all. I have tried to set another template, but it also doesn't work. 
About binding - I have added the Converter just to see what is bound like [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html) and Binding is correct.

---

UPD : Problem resolved when I understand that Custom Control should be as separate `dll`. So I just move my code into separate project and add reference to Main project...

Comment: Please check that you are declare your converter in Resources block with "ImagePathConverter" name. If you're just using class name it will not work.

Comment: @VadimMartynov, yes, I did it.

Comment: Nice. Next ensure that your binding not throwing an error. You can check Output window in visual studio to show binding errors. Then, ensure that your property bind to this binding.

Comment: @VadimMartynov, no errors... let me check again bindings

Comment: As a note, `return bi.Clone()` in your converter doesn't make sense. Instead just write `return bi`.

Comment: @Clemens, Logically, yes, I should just return `bi` but in this case image displayed only first time, when you again goes to this page, Image are not displayed

Comment: Are there any objects in list _Images_?

Comment: @dontbyteme, Collection `Images` contains type `Image` - custom Type, which has property `FileLocation`

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the property FileLocation to something like

```
public object FileLocation
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
             return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)PathToImage));
        }
        catch 
        {
             return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<flipViewControl:FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" Name="ImagesFlipView" SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=ProductImagesBullets, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0">
    <flipViewControl:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding FileLocation}" />  
        </DataTemplate>
    </flipViewControl:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</flipViewControl:FlipView>
```

without using a Converter?